# NoSuchMethodException aspectOf in aspectj load time weaving in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I used [spring ltw documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw) to configure load time weaving in my spring boot app.
below dependencies are in pom file:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

aop.xml is configured as below and have placed in resources/META-INF

```xml
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
    "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="com.tosan.http.server.starter.logger.ServiceLogger"/>
    </weaver>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect"/>
</aspects>
```

I also enabled aspectj load time weaving with spring boot configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving()
public class DemoConfig {

   @Bean
   public TestAspect testAspect() {
       TestAspect testAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(TestAspect.class);
       return testAspect;
   }
}
```

on running program javaagent is passed as below:

```
-javaagent:\aspectjweaver.jar 
-javaagent:\spring-instrument-5.3.23.jar
```

app give noSuchMethodException on start up:

```
[AppClassLoader@368239c8] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.Object 
com.tosan.http.server.starter.logger.ServiceLogger.log(org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint))' 
in Type 'com.tosan.http.server.starter.logger.ServiceLogger' (ServiceLogger.java:17) advised 
by around advice from 'com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'testAspect' defined in class path resource [com/sample/demo/DemoConfig.class]: Bean 
instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect]: Factory method 'testAspect' threw exception; nested 
exception is org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing 
com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect.aspectOf()
at
```

I should also mention that when i add ajc compiler(with com.nickwongdev plugin) app starts fine but the aspect execute twice. also tried ajc compiler and only aspectjWeaver as agent and it gives error for not finding spring specific weaver classes and tried ajc compiler with only spring weaver agent that doesn't give any error but aspect is not executed.
any help would be appreciated.

Complete code sample on [github](https://github.com/minakh1993/LoadTimeWeavingSample).

upadate: problem solved by adding the path of aspect in weaver:

```
<include within="com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect"/>
```

I also noticed by removing @EnableLoadTimeWeaving() nothing happen and ltw is done in presence or absence of this annotation. This annotation only force the presence of spring weaver as javaagent in runtime.

correct code is updated on github.

Comment: Following a manual for the 3.2.0 version of the framework where you are on 5.3 isn't the best idea. Also why both java-agents? You should only need 1. Next to that loadtimeweaving in Spring Boot is a bit of a pain to get to work (imho).

Comment: I searched alot and looked at many tutorials they where all the same with a little less or more. Yes definitely ltw in spring is pain but i have a requirement and also so curious about it. Thank's for your advice i will try to find related document. And i also tried one agent but got the same exception.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have a few educated guesses what might be wrong with your approach. But I cannot say for sure, unless you post a link to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally a Maven project on GitHub. If I can reproduce your problem, it will be easy to fix. But I do not like speculating, possibly needing multiple iterations due to incomplete information.

Comment: I uploaded the code in my github and put the link in post. thanks in advance. https://github.com/minakh1993/LoadTimeWeavingSample

Comment: IMO you don't need to configure the bean with TestAspect testAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(TestAspect.class);

Comment: I know i added it to show the exception on startup for simplicity...otherwise the exception shows itself on calling the pointcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the GitHub repo. It was easy to fix the problem like this, you did yourself a great favour by preparing it.

Firstly, the pointcut and weaver configuration does not fit the example class name. Please change

```java
@Pointcut("execution(public * com.tosan.http.server.starter.logger.ServiceLogger.log(..))")
```

to

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(com.sample.demo.TestAnnotation)")
```

because I guess you want to intercept methods with marker annotations.

In *aop.xml*, remove line

```xml
<include within="com.tosan.http.server.starter.logger.ServiceLogger"/>
```

or replace it by something like

```xml
<include within="com.sample.demo..*"/>
```

Next, get rid of factory method `@Bean TestAspect testAspect()`. You do not need it. Instead, in order to test the aspect, simply change the main method to:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      appContext.getBean(TestController.class).test();
    }
  }
```

If now you run your application like before, the console log says:

```
(...)
[AppClassLoader@4d7e1886] info register aspect com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect
(...)
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

(...)
[AppClassLoader@4d7e1886] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.sample.demo.controller.TestController.test())' in Type 'com.sample.demo.controller.TestController' (TestController.java:17) advised by around advice from 'com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
(...)
2023-01-04 20:25:47.599  INFO 20208 --- [           main] c.sample.demo.controller.TestController  : {
  "service" : "test",
  "request" : { }
}
aspect invocation
test
2023-01-04 20:25:47.611  INFO 20208 --- [           main] c.sample.demo.controller.TestController  : {
  "service" : "test",
  "duration" : "0.026s",
  "response" : { }
}
(...)
```

Please note `aspect invocation` printed by the aspect.

Comment: Actually the pointcut was correct i wanted a pointcut in a dependency. The annotation was left in project from previous attempts. For the same pointcut as before does aop.xml have problem?

Comment: So why does on startup log shows that weaving has happend? But aspectOf method doesn't exist? I sincerely appreciate for the time you spend.

Comment: Like @Simon Martinelli previously said in a comment: It is simply not necessary to create a bean for a native AspectJ aspect, unless you want to inject Spring components into them. Keep it simple!

Comment: But if you like to keep the `@Bean` method for the aspect, it should work. For me, it works nicely. Add this method to your aspect: `public void doSomething() { System.out.println("aspect doing something"); }` Then, add this to your main method: `appContext.getBean(TestAspect.class).doSomething();` That will print `aspect doing something`, FWIW.

Comment: i updated the github repository with the annotation pointcut and something really strange is happening. when this line exist <include within="com.sample.demo..*"/> the other pointcut in dependency is working fine but when i remove this one the other pointcut doesn't work with the same exception no aspectOf method exist. what is the reason of this behavior? actually the problem is now having one pointcut  in dependency classes.

Comment: I also noticed that @EnableLoadTimeWeaving() annotation is useless. when i remove it there is no reaction and the weaving is done. is there any way to disable load time weaving with a spring property on runtime? because there was suggestions on web on using @EnableLoadTimeWeaving() and @Profile together in order to use ltw in specific profiles.

Comment: I answer my first question as this : when ever we want to specify a pointcut in other library there must be two weaver path: one for the path of aspect and one for the path of  pointcut in order to work. problem solved by adding this to another weaver path:  <include within="com.sample.demo.aspect.TestAspect"/>

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help  kriegaex. the problem was absence of aspect path in aop.xml that i updated it and solved the problem. i assume that configuring  load time weaving with spring profiles is not possible since @EnableLoadTimeWeaving have no affect.